# Is it possible for me to test my webapp in China to see what is blocked?

Tags: web, web-applications

I work for a company and we are setting up a customer base in China to use it. We are having a couple of issues with content being blocked and breaking the site. We need to find a VPN to emulate the fact that we are based in China when looking at the website.

I have tried pureVPN and tunnelbear but they don't seem to be affected by the firewall that blocks everything. I understand that this is the opposite of what a lot of people use VPNs for when it comes to China but I need to find a way around this in order to get our app working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I have sorted this all out by purchasing a server from aliyun.com and VNCing into the box with Ubuntu desktop installed. This works perfectly.

The boxes are really cheap as well and there is a 15day free trial on their ECS instances which are essentially a clone of AWS's EC2 boxes.

Comment: How did you manage to create an account? I never got the confirmation token in my mobile..